# Any idea about Elasticsearch Aggregation?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

1. Please guide me to understand *Elastic Aggregation* with simple examples.
2. And also please tell me how can we achieve customization in *Elastic Search* like for    example if we want to extract data from some field and that too if it satisfies some   criteria...etc.
3. How can we achieve like this functionality in *Elastic Search* using *JAVA*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation is a utility to derive data about your resultset as a whole. For instance, if you query for all employees for a company, you can use aggregation to get the average of all their salaries. Here is a sample query:

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search?search_type=count
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "price": {
                        "gte": 10000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "single_avg_price": {
            "avg" : { "field" : "price" }
        }
    }
}
```

^ this example shows how to use aggregation.

I am not sure about what you mean from #2. It sounds like you just want to do a simple query. If that is the case, the above example should be good enough. The query is basically saying 'select all cars who's price is > 10,000' and 'get me the average price for the cars in the results'

edit:

## 3 ElasticSearch has a Java API. Some examples are here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/get.html

Comment: Thanks @coffeaddict for your fast reply. I appreciate that. Since this was my very first post in this site,I am very happy to know people are so experienced and helping.